# linq query generate defferent results

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have linq query one in linq query expresion and other in lambda expression but both generate differnt result please some tell me whats the deffernce between the queries

```
var result = from c in displayedCompanies
                     select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.CampusId), c.CampusName, c.CampusCode };
```

the abouve query generate the following result

`[["10","Ken Mazar Campus","01"],["20","Ken Kabul","02"]]`

```
var result = displayedCompanies.Select(c => new { c.CampusId, c.CampusName, c.CampusCode });
```

this query generate the following result

```
[{"CampusId":10,"CampusName":"Ken Mazar Campus","CampusCode":"01"},
      {"CampusId":20,"CampusName":"Ken Kabul","CampusCode":"02"}]
```

ant the following result is generating after i conver the result to json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in short you are doing something like this:

**linq query**

```
displayedCompanies
            .Select (c => new String[] { Convert.ToString (c.CampusId), c.CampusName});
```

which returns as a array result without column name, just values.

**lambda expression**

```
    displayedCompanies
             .Select (c => new {CampusId= c.CampusId, CampusName= c.CampusName})
```

this returns with columns name.

Answer (score 2):

```
select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.CampusId), c.CampusName, c.CampusCode }
```

The above creates an array with 3 elements. As a result, the linq query returns an array of array

```
displayedCompanies.Select(c => new { c.CampusId, c.CampusName, c.CampusCode });
```

The above query creates anyonymus object with 3 properties namely CampusId, CampusName, CampusCode etc. When converted to json it creates an object and hence returns an array of objects.